Powering STM32 Directly with a DC-DC Converter: Considerations and Recommendations
I'm a bit concerned about directly powering an STM32 with a DC-DC converter. For a project, I want to supply 3.3V at 20mA from a 12.6V 55mA power source, and I’m considering using a DC-DC converter for this purpose. My goal is to keep the input current to the converter at a minimum and ensure enough current remains available for the rest of the circuit from the power supply. I plan to use a small, ready-made module like the MP2307 to directly power the VDD pins of the STM32F103C8T6.
For the VDDA pin, however, I thought it might be wiser to use a separate regulator, like the AP2204, to prevent the analog section from being affected by noise from the DC-DC converter output. This way, I aim to shield the analog parts of the MCU from potential noise.
However, I still have reservations about using a DC-DC converter for this purpose since I’ve never powered an MCU directly from one before. In the past, I would only use regulators, but now my power source is limited, and I want to achieve maximum efficiency with minimal current draw, which is why I'm leaning towards a DC-DC converter. I’m curious to hear your thoughts on this. Could you please guide me on this approach?

The Vref pin will be the most sensitive. So if possible you can pick some lower voltage there, derived from the general Vdd but with a voltage ref (shunt or serial).

VDDA must generally be the same potential as VDD.
It may allow up to 300mV of difference during power-up and operation.
The data sheet recommends to use same source for VDD and VDDA.
If you don't, and the supplies come from two different regulators, there is a risk of MCU getting damaged if the voltages differ by more than 300mV at any point.

I think he wants to use the same voltage only a different source.

@0___________ Yes and using different source makes it very complex to make both supplies to be equal within 300mV while they start up or shut down.

You're right, but I do not think it will make any difference in this short period of time, as the MCU's analog part is not enabled. It has to be enabled by the firmware. Using two supplies is a quite common practice. BTW I UV your answer.

@0___________ The MCU documentation clearly says they cannot differ more than 300mV max during startup or operation, so it does matter. The analog pins are used by many things inside the MCU even if you don't enable any analog systems, for example the RC oscillators and power-on reset depend on AVDD. All this reads in the data sheet if you search "AVDD".

@Justme Thank you for your response. Since yesterday, I've been busy gathering information online on similar topics. Based on what I've learned, powering the MCU with a single voltage source is indeed the best approach. As you mentioned, the 300mV differential tolerance is truly a challenging limit to control, making it almost impossible for me to keep the MCU within these bounds. Therefore, I plan to power the MCU directly with a DC-DC converter and add a low-pass (L-C) filter to the AVDD pin.

@Justme Additionally, I tested the module extensively under different load conditions and events like power on/off while monitoring it under an oscilloscope, and I found no issues. It also seems that many people use an MCU directly with a buck converter in this way, which has led me to decide on using a converter as well. Now, the main task is determining the values for the L and C components. What are your thoughts on this? Or do you have any other methods you typically use?

@Nasah I would read manufacturer suggestions, and would not use an inductor at all, not without proper damping anyway. Pure LC filter with chip that pulls current in spikes means it may ring.


You can use different sources if you keep the VDDx the same.
I would recommend Vss separation as well as noise from the DC/DC can also affect the ground. Correctly design the Vss plane and have Vssa separated from the Vss (star configuration and I would place a bead there)


Both two suggestions are against what you would generally do in such a case. Can you explain why it is OK in this case? The MCU will not tolerate more than 300mV of difference on supplies which is difficult to manage with two different regulators, and connecting GNDD and GNDA with a ferrite is not how ST tells to design the star ground for them.
